# Keeping lilypond scores separate from each other in Git

Tags: git, lilypond

I compose and arrange music as a hobby, using Sibelius for initial drafting and producing audio and Lilypond for typesetting final copies. Being source code, I put my prints under version control. Note that I'm fairly inexperienced with Git beyond branching and merging, etc.

I have all my scores in a directory structure like this:

```
scores/
| -- some_score/
|    | -- Makefile (makes/updates all PDFs)
|    | -- src/
|    |    | -- (all the ly files)
|    | -- prints/
|    |    | -- (all the PDFs)
| -- other_score/ (similar structure)
```

etc...

I ran `git init` in the root dir, and I would work on each score separately in its own `(score_title)-dev` branch, pushing to `master` once I had a printable draft, say, for each part. As I've been jumping between projects, though, I've found that merging the `dev` branches into `master` gets messy.

I read a little about submodules and have considered it; I also read a bit about subtrees, but those made even less sense to me. Is there a clean way to manage all this? Do I just need to revise how I work with my branches?

Comment: "pushing to master" Do you mean merging to master? You cannot push a dev branch to master. Well, maybe you can, but you'd better not.

Comment: And no, stay away from submodules etc. Just stay away.

Comment: Regarding the first comment, yes. I proofread at least twice, and that must have slipped. Yes, I meant merging. As to your second, that's what I figured

Comment: Looking back on this, I am not quite sure why you found merging the `dev` branches into `master` messy. If each `dev` branch is really just focused on a separate directory, I would expect the merging of those branches to be relatively painless, resulting in no merge conflicts. That being said, for personal projects I hew as closely to the master branch as I can, as I don't generally need the power that extra branches provide (unless I'm trying something out that might break everything in my repo, for example). I think one or multiple repos could work fine here.

Answer (score 2):

You are running into these issues because you are slightly abusing git as Dropbox: Having all projects in one repository leads to messing up merges at some point in time.

Better approach: Use one repository per score. Private repos are free on Github nowadays so there would be no increased cost factor and every project could have a clean commit history on its own.

Submodules should not be used here as they serve an entirely different purpose.

Comment: So the best way would have a `scores` dir on my local computer, but a git repo for everything in that second level (referring to the diagram in OP)?

Comment: I can't agree with this. I have literally hundreds of different iOS application projects in the same repository and they do not "mess up merge pushes".

Comment: @harmonica141 Thanks for this answer. I did some digging and came across GitHub's topics feature, as well as the language filter (I did mention my inexperience, after). Those serve me well enough. Of course the simple answer proves to be the best

Comment: @harmonica141 I have data for about 100 pieces of music stored in a single git repo, but I wish I had created a separate repo for each. Each piece of music really is a separate "project": for example, to collaborate on a piece of music, you just want to share the one piece, not all the music you've ever written. And I'd love a clean commit history for each piece of music. Maybe, one day, I'll move to one repo per song (but what preserving commit history? eek!)